# How to sort hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have hashmap and its keys are like "folder/1.txt,folder/2.txt,folder/3.txt" and value has these text files data.

Now i am stucked. I want to sort this list. But it does not let me do it :(
Here is my hashmap data type:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

following function work good but it is for arraylist not for hashmap.

```
Collections.sort(values, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

I also tried MapTree but it also didn't work, or may be I couldn't make it work. I used
following steps to sort the code with maptree

```
HashMap testMap = new HashMap();
Map sortedMap = new TreeMap(testMap);
```

any other way to do it??

I have one doubt as my keys are (folder/1.txt, folder/2.txt ) may be that's why?

Comment: Do you want to sort the Map Strings, or do you want to sort each value list of Strings?

Comment: -1 - This question is incomprehensible.  All the attempted answers are guessing what the question really means.

Comment: You are right Stephen, we are all guessing!

Comment: LOL, that was probably our first mistake.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that you want the list of keys sorted.

If your hashmap is called `h`, then try this:

```
SortedSet<String> sortedKeys = new TreeSet<String>(h.keySet());
```

Comment: thanks, It worked !
sorry for if my question made your guys guess!

Comment: (-1)You can't new SortedSet(), it's an interface. Should be something like sortedKeys = new TreeSet<String>(h.keySet());

Comment: RealHowTo -- Thank you.  You're right.  I have fixed my answer.

Comment: Of course you can "new" an interface - it just means that you have to provide the entire implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just do this?

```
Map<String, ValueObject> testMap = new TreeMap<String, ValueObject>();
```

where `ValueObject` is whatever class you're using for values.

**Edit:** this is based on some assumptions -- waiting to get more information to see what OP really needs.

Comment: I did read the post -- he doesn't explicitly say whether he wants to sort based on the keys or the values.  Neither does he say if the keys are Strings or Files.  So I assumed he wants to sort based on String keys, which would be automatic with a TreeMap, which he should just use instead of a HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Use a TreeMap, and implement the Comparator interface for the folder paths.

The comparator should compare two keys according to what ever rules you want, and pass that comparator to the constructor of the TreeMap. If sorting by pure alphabetical rules are ok, then you can skip this step. If you want to do something special with the paths, then you will need to define what that is in the comparator.

Comment: Tree map sorts the *keys* not the elements!

Comment: why would you want to sort the values? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You wrote "elements" first. Now it sounds okay, but SO wont let me take away the downvote until you edit again!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess was that use use `File` objects rather than `String` objects as keys. But then I noted that you say your key is `"folder/1.txt,folder/2.txt,folder/3.txt"` and your values are of type `Collection<Strings>`. If this is so, maybe your solutions should be

```
map.put("folder/1.txt", ...);
map.put("folder/2.txt", ...);
map.put("folder/3.txt", ...);
```

rather than

```
map.put("folder/1.txt,folder/2.txt,folder/3.txt", new ArrayList(...));
```

to get the single files sorted with a `TreeMap` as you tried.

Comment: He says his keys are Strings...

Comment: But he seems to use comma separated filenames as keys, so I edited my post to have another guess. Please remove downvote.

Comment: Sure thing, we'll see if he ever clarifies what exactly he's doing :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe HashMaps do not guarantee any ordering when you iterate through the keys. The iteration order depends on the buckets and collisions.

You may want to put the values into some other collection and then sort them.

Comment: HashMaps do NOT guarantee ordering in the keys.  According to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: true for HashMap itself but have a look at LinkedHashMap (which extends HashMap). It guarantees order of keys like they were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use LinkedHashMap, when calling keySet() it gives you back items in a sorted way, as you added the to the map through put().